# Call two different action types from one redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I've been able to get by with basic sagas implementation for now but my app is getting a little more complex. I chose sagas for the asynchronous capabilities but seem to have misunderstood how things work.

I have a global search input within my application that needs to make two different api calls (different data objects), but the search input also has it's own loading states based on the search/ status of api calls. Based on this information this is the flow of the application:

1. Search happens (dispatches the action `GLOBAL_SEARCH_REQUEST`)
2. The saga watcher for `GLOBAL_SEARCH_REQUEST` kicks off (sets loading to true for the input)
3. In that saga - make a call to get all users / subscriptions that match the search query
4. On success, set loading for the input to false
5. On failure, set error

the global search request saga

```
function* globalSearchRequestSaga(action) {
  const { query } = action
  console.log(`searching subscriptions and users for : ${query}`)
  try {
    yield put(fetchUsersRequest(query))
    // call for the subscriptions (leaving it out for simplicity in this example)
    yield put(globalSearchSuccess(query))
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error}`)
    yield put(globalSearchFailure(error.message))
  }
}
```

where the fetch users saga looks like

```
export function* fetchUsersRequestSaga(action) {
  const { query } = action
  const path = `${root}/users`
  try {
    const users = yield axios.get(path, { crossDomain: true })
    yield put(fetchUsersSuccess(query, users.data))
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error : ${error}`)
    yield put(fetchUsersFailure(query, error.message))
  }
}
```

(very basic)

If I do things this way, there is an issue where the the `GLOBAL_SEARCH_SUCCESS` action is executed before the completion of the request for users ( and I imagine the same thing if I added in subscriptions api call as well). One solution I found is if I change the line

```
yield put(fetchUsersRequest(query))
```

to

```
yield call(fetchUsersRequestSaga, fetchUsersRequest(query))
```

where `fetchUsersRequestSaga` is the saga from above, and `fetchUsersRequest(query)` is the action creator for fetching users. This causes the asnyc functionality to work, and `GLOBAL_SEARCH_SUCCESS` waits for the return of the users (correct behavior).

The only issue with this is that the `FETCH_USERS_REQUEST` action is no longer logged to the store.

I am wondering if there is a way to either get this to properly log to the store, or return to my previous implementation with proper blocking on the `put(fetchUsersRequest(query))`

Comment: You could yield a [take](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takepattern) on fetch user success or fail but since you put multiple fetch user actions you have to wait for the exact success or fail that you just fired and that means giving your fetch user action an id and have success and fail use that id.

Comment: So you are saying inside of the `fetchUsersRequestSaga` do `yield take(fetchUsersSuccess(query, users.data)` and that would block the execution of the `globalSearchSuccess()` in the other saga?

Comment: I added an answer, let me know if that worked. Made something like this in a general api layer a while ago so may have missed some yield (maybe waitFor needs to `return yield waitFor(id)` when it recursively calls itself.

Answer (score 3):

The `put` function is a non-blocking action. It won't wait till the promise/api request resolves.

I would suggest you to just call sagas directly instead of dispatching actions.

```
try {
   yield call(fetchUsersRequestSaga, query);
   yield call(globalSearchSaga, query); // or whatever its called
}
```

`call` is a blocking action. It will wait until the request finishes, so both if your calls will execute in proper order.

Comment: OP already tried call but then fetch user is not dispatched and the reducer for fetch user is never called.

Comment: @HMR Then why not to move the 'fetching user logic' inside the saga? Or just dispatch it inside saga, but disconnect the `globalSearchRequestSaga` from listening to that action.

Comment: where would this be called from though?

Comment: Yeah! Because there are two sagas I am dealing with, the users and search, and you are saying to call both of them inside this try (when I would think that I would be calling them from the `searchSaga`)

Comment: @erp You have to call them inside `globalSearchRequestSaga`, just like you did above. But call instead of put action.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with sagas but here is some code that will give you a general idea how to wait for a dispatched action.

The way it works is that when you fetch and want to wait for it to fail or succeed you give the fetch action an id, then you can pass that to the waitFor function while simultaneously dispatch the action.

If you don't want or need to wait for it then you can just dispatch the action without an id and it'll still work:

```
const addId = (id => fn => (...args) => ({
  ...fn(...args),
  id: id++,
}))(0);
const withId = ({ id }, action) => ({ action, id });

function* waitFor(id) {
  const action = yield take('*');
  if (action.id === id) {
    return action;
  }
  return waitFor(id);
}

function* globalSearchRequestSaga(action) {
  const { query } = action;
  console.log(
    `searching subscriptions and users for : ${query}`
  );
  try {
    //add id to action (id is unique)
    const action = addId(fetchUsersRequest, query);
    //dispatch the action and then wait for resulting action
    //  with the same id
    yield put(action);
    const result = yield waitFor(action.id);
    // call for the subscriptions (leaving it out for simplicity in this example)
    yield put(globalSearchSuccess(query));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error}`);
    yield put(globalSearchFailure(error.message));
  }
}

export function* fetchUsersRequestSaga(action) {
  const { query } = action;
  const path = `${root}/users`;
  try {
    const users = yield axios.get(path, {
      crossDomain: true,
    });
    yield put(//add original id to success action
      withId(action, fetchUsersSuccess(query, users.data))
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error : ${error}`);
    yield put(
      withId(//add original id to fail action
        action,
        fetchUsersFailure(query, error.message)
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. It will take me some time to look over this

Comment: @erp I edited the answer, I think it was `yield all([put(action),call(waitFor(action.id))]);` if you want to dispatch a fetch action and wait for another action with the same id (success or fail). Maybe `yield put(action); yied call(waitFor(action.id))]);` will work as well but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think that it might be a little bit overcomplicated for this problem

Comment: @erp Had a look at the old code and updated the answer, you can dispatch the fetch action and then just `const result yield waitFor(id of the action just dispatched)` , result will be either the success or fail action that fetch saga will dispatch.